# Spring Security Apache Ant URL Filtering on Extension or Suffix

Tags: java, ant, spring-security

I would like to require authentication on URLs that have a specific extension, but am having trouble understanding how the Apache Ant parser in Spring Security functions. It seems to only support parsing from left to right, instead of using something more common like a regex. Essentially, I would like something like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**.html*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Where any URL that has ".html" at the end requires authentication. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the [request matcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-request-matcher):

> - **request-matcher** Defines the `RequestMatcher` strategy used in the `FilterChainProxy` and the beans created by the `intercept-url` to match incoming requests. Options are currently `ant`, `regex` and `ciRegex`, for ant, regular-expression and case-insensitive regular-expression repsectively. A separate instance is created for eachintercept-url element using its pattern and method attributes. Ant paths are matched using an `AntPathRequestMatcher` and regular expressions are matched using a `RegexRequestMatcher`. See the Javadoc for these classes for more details on exactly how the matching is preformed. Ant paths are the default strategy.

But [AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html?is-external=true) should do it:

> Some examples:
>
> - `com/t?st.jsp` - matches `com/test.jsp` but also `com/tast.jsp` or `com/txst.jsp`
> - `com/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files in the `com` directory
> - `com/**/test.jsp` - matches all `test.jsp` files underneath the `com` path
> - `org/springframework/**/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files underneath the `org/springframework` path
> - `org/**/servlet/bla.jsp` - matches `org/springframework/servlet/bla.jsp` but  also `org/springframework/testing/servlet/bla.jsp` and `org/servlet/bla.jsp`

Comment: I switched to ciRegex. I'm wondering if my issue with the AntPathMatcher was because of the '/' in front, but when I try it like that it doesn't seem to work.